# Does argument unpacking use iteration or item-getting?

Tags: python, iterator, arguments

I'm using Python 2.7.3.

Consider a dummy class with custom (albeit bad) iteration and item-getting behavior:

```
class FooList(list):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self)
    def next(self):
        return 3
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return 3
```

Make an example and see the weird behavior:

```
>>> zz = FooList([1,2,3])

>>> [x for x in zz]
# Hangs because of the self-reference in `__iter__`.

>>> zz[0]
3

>>> zz[1]
3
```

But now, let's make a function and then do argument unpacking on `zz`:

```
def add3(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

>>> add3(*zz)
6
# I expected either 9 or for the interpreter to hang like the comprehension!
```

So, argument unpacking is somehow getting the item data from `zz` but not by either iterating over the object with its implemented iterator and also not by doing a poor man's iterator and calling `__getitem__` for as many items as the object has.

So the question is: how does the syntax `add3(*zz)` acquire the data members of `zz` if not by these methods? Am I just missing one other common pattern for getting data members from a type like this?

My goal is to see if I could write a class that implements iteration or item-getting in such a way that it changes what the argument unpacking syntax means for that class. After trying the two example above, I'm now wondering how argument unpacking gets at the underlying data and whether the programmer can influence that behavior. Google for this only gave back a sea of results explaining the basic usage of the `*args` syntax.

I don't have a use case for needing to do this and I am not claiming it is a good idea. I just want to see how to do it for the sake of curiosity.

**Added**

Since the built-in types are treated specially, here's an example with `object` where I just maintain a list object and implement my own get and set behavior to emulate list.

```
class FooList(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __iter__(self): raise ValueError
    def next(self): return 3
    def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.lst.__getitem__(idx)
    def __setitem__(self, idx, itm): self.lst.__setitem__(idx, itm)
```

In this case,

```
In [234]: zz = FooList([1,2,3])

In [235]: [x for x in zz]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-ad3bb7659c84> in <module>()
----> 1 [x for x in zz]

<ipython-input-233-dc9284300db1> in __iter__(self)
      2     def __init__(self, lst):
      3         self.lst = lst
----> 4     def __iter__(self): raise ValueError
      5     def next(self): return 3
      6     def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.lst.__getitem__(idx)

ValueError:

In [236]: add_3(*zz)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-236-f9bbfdc2de5c> in <module>()
----> 1 add_3(*zz)

<ipython-input-233-dc9284300db1> in __iter__(self)
      2     def __init__(self, lst):
      3         self.lst = lst
----> 4     def __iter__(self): raise ValueError
      5     def next(self): return 3
      6     def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.lst.__getitem__(idx)

ValueError:
```

But instead, if I ensure iteration stops and always returns 3, I can get what I was shooting to play around with in the first case:

```
class FooList(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.iter_loc = -1
    def __iter__(self): return self
    def next(self): 
        if self.iter_loc < len(self.lst)-1:
            self.iter_loc += 1
            return 3
        else:
            self.iter_loc = -1
            raise StopIteration
    def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.lst.__getitem__(idx)
    def __setitem__(self, idx, itm): self.lst.__setitem__(idx, itm)
```

Then I see this, which is what I originally expected:

```
In [247]: zz = FooList([1,2,3])

In [248]: ix = iter(zz)

In [249]: ix.next()
Out[249]: 3

In [250]: ix.next()
Out[250]: 3

In [251]: ix.next()
Out[251]: 3

In [252]: ix.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-252-29d4ae900c28> in <module>()
----> 1 ix.next()

<ipython-input-246-5479fdc9217b> in next(self)
     10         else:
     11             self.iter_loc = -1
---> 12             raise StopIteration
     13     def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.lst.__getitem__(idx)
     14     def __setitem__(self, idx, itm): self.lst.__setitem__(idx, itm)

StopIteration:

In [253]: ix = iter(zz)

In [254]: ix.next()
Out[254]: 3

In [255]: ix.next()
Out[255]: 3

In [256]: ix.next()
Out[256]: 3

In [257]: ix.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-257-29d4ae900c28> in <module>()
----> 1 ix.next()

<ipython-input-246-5479fdc9217b> in next(self)
     10         else:
     11             self.iter_loc = -1
---> 12             raise StopIteration
     13     def __getitem__(self, idx): return self.lst.__getitem__(idx)
     14     def __setitem__(self, idx, itm): self.lst.__setitem__(idx, itm)

StopIteration:

In [258]: add_3(*zz)
Out[258]: 9

In [259]: zz[0]
Out[259]: 1

In [260]: zz[1]
Out[260]: 2

In [261]: zz[2]
Out[261]: 3

In [262]: [x for x in zz]
Out[262]: [3, 3, 3]
```

**Summary**

1. The syntax `*args` relies on iteration only. For built-in types this happens in a way that is not directly overrideable in classes that inherit from the built-in type.
2. These two are functionally equivalent:

   `foo(*[x for x in args])`

   `foo(*args)`
3. These are not equivalent even for finite data structures.

   `foo(*args)`

   `foo(*[args[i] for i in range(len(args))])`

Comment: I think you'll discover more interesting information if you derive `FooList` from `object` rather than `list`.

Comment: This doesn't hang because of infinite iteration; it hangs because `__iter__(self)` indirectly calls itself recursively, so it takes infinite recursion to even _get_ an iterator. You can remove the `next` entirely and get the same behavior…

Comment: I also created a separate `FooListIter` class and had `__iter__` return an instance of that, with the same `next` behavior as above, and it does the same. But thank you for the point about `iter` calling itself here.

Comment: You could add some debug statements to all of your methods, like `print 'now executing next'` ...

Comment: @EMS: You can change what argument-unpacking does for a class, but only by changing what iteration does for the class.  That is, you can't make a class that does one thing for argument-unpacking and a different thing for other iteration.

Comment: That was my suspicion, but it seems false for `list` (and other built-in types). Here, in fact, my `iter` implementation is totally wrong. If I ask for `iter(zz)` it hangs. But `*zz` still works, I guess because it ignores my implemented `__iter__` and uses `list`'s `__iter__` regardless? I agree if I inherited from `object` instead, and then referenced an internal data member that was a `list` it should hang. I was surprised it did not directly here.

Comment: @EMS: Everything I'm saying only applies for user-defined types that don't inherit from builtin types (other than `object`).  The builtin types have their own iteration/unpacking behavior which is basically functionally equivalent to the iterator protocol, but doesn't actually use the iterator protocol, so you can't reliably override or customize the behavior by subclassing builtin types and trying to define `__iter__` and stuff.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn. Your most recent comment is precisely the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Related:  [Change what the *splat and **splatty-splat operators do to my object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22365847/674039)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have been bitten by one of Python's most irritating warts: builtin types and subclasses of them are treated magically in some places.

Since your type subclasses from `list`, Python magically reaches into its internals to unpack it.  It doesn't use the real iterator API at all.  If you insert `print` statements inside your `next` and `__getitem__`, you'll see that neither one is being called.  This behavior cannot be overridden; instead, you would have to write your own class that reimplements the builtin types.  You could try using [`UserList`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#module-UserList); I haven't checked whether that would work.

The answer to your question is that argument unpacking uses iteration.  However, iteration itself can use `__getitem__` if there is no explicit `__iter__` defined.  You can't make a class that defines argument-unpacking behavior that is different from the normal iteration behavior.

The iterator protocol (basically "how `__iter__` works") shouldn't be assumed to apply to types that subclass builtin types like `list`.  If you subclass a builtin, your subclass may magically behave like the underlying builtin in certain situations, without making use of your customize magic methods (like `__iter__`).  If you want to customize behavior fully and reliably, you can't subclass from builtin types (except, of course, `object`).

Comment: So for `list`, `tuple`, and `dict`, I cannot interrupt whatever internals are being called to get the data members during argument unpacking?

Comment: @EMS: Why would you want to? If you don't want `list`/`tuple`/`dict` magic behavior, don't inherit from them; you can just keep a `list`/`tuple`/`dict` member and delegate to it (exactly where you want, and not where you don't want).

Comment: I didn't say that I wanted to.

Comment: @EMS: You could try using `UserList` or `UserDict`.

Comment: @EMS: Then why did you ask that question? It's like asking "Can I monkeypatch methods on builtin types" and then saying you didn't want to monkeypatch methods on builtin types.

Comment: That's exactly right. I want to know what I can do, not because I want to then do it but just to know what's possible.

Comment: if __iter__ exists, but throws an exception, will python abort or back off to try using __getitem__ instead?

Comment: It looks like the unpacking syntax just relies on `iter` behavior. I'll add a proper `object` version to my question to demonstrate.