# initialize ordereddict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new in Python.

I am trying to create many `ordereddict`,but because I am filling it out in messed sequence I had to create a function to pass in the normal dict to get the order I want.

```
info = dict()
info['age'] = 3
...

keys=['id','name','age','ck_id','image']
def fix_order(my_dict):
    new_queue = OrderedDict()
    for k in keys:
        new_queue[k] = item[k]
    return new_queue
```

What I want to do is to create a simple class which already has the order I want no matter the sequence of filling it.

I checked this question[How to create an OrderedDict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114985/how-to-create-an-ordereddict-in-python), but this assumes I have the values first hand.

i.e what I want `info = my_dict()` #already has the sequence (order) built in

Comment: Cant you define some default None value for keys wich are yet to update ?

Comment: also as of 3.7 'normal `dict` is also ordered.

Comment: Why does the order matter if the keys are fixed values?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  I yield the dictionaries to `CSVExporter`.

Comment: @Vaibhav Yes, but is that the "pythonic"  way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know about CSVExporter (and couldn't find anything about such a thing after googling it...). What is it exactly? (can you share some link to its documentation?) And are you sure that it expects an ordereddict to be used?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille [https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html], it can take in any sort of dictionary,but when I am passing different ordered dict, it gives not ideal results

Comment: Firsly, you use some `item` dict but your function gets `my_dict`. Secondly, for getting item or a default value use `my_dict.get(k, default_value_here)`

Comment: The doc you linked to says 'To specify columns to export and their order use FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS', which is a list of field names. That would be the normal, logical way for the library you use to know the order of fields. Maybe you should ask a question with your real practical problem.

Comment: What is the nesting structure of your dict to maintain uniqueness? Would a sorted list or JSON data be a possible option?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to have a data structure that gives you the same operations as dict, but if iterate over gives items in a precise order.

If this is the case you can override the methods that gives out iterables: the `__iter__` method, the `key` method, the `values` method and the `items` method (maybe there are others which I can't remember)

There is a basic class you can start off. (I.e this will only iterate over the elements you specified, but probably you want to extend to iterate over the other elements, too)

```py
from collections import UserDict

class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.order = kwargs.pop('order')
        super().__init__(*args)
    def change_order(self, order: list):
        self.order = order

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.order:
            if key in self:
                yield key

    def keys(self):
        for key in self.order:
            if key in self:
                yield key

    def values(self):
        for key in self.order:
            if key in self:
                yield self[key]

    def items(self):
        for key in self.order:
            if key in self:
                yield key, self[key]
```

There is a test:

```py
d = MyDict({"b" : 2, "c": 3, "a": 1}, order=["a","b","c"])
print(d)

for k in d:
    print(k, end=" ")
#a b c
print()

for k in d.keys():
    print(k, end=" ")
#a b c
print()

for v in d.values():
    print(v, end=" ")
#1 2 3
print()

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"{k}-{v}", end=" ")
#a-1 b-2 c-3
```

You can override `__repr__` and `__str__` if you want your dictionary to be converted in string (and printed) in the order you want, too