# Python magic * or ** method equivalent

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a python method equivalent to `*` and `**` magic?

So, what I mean by this is instead of doing:

```
a = (1,2,3)
method(*a)
```

Instead do something like:

```
a = (1,2,3)
method(remove_magic(a))
```

Whilst reading through code I see `*` and `**` and just wish there was a nicer more readable way of doing this. I am hoping there is something within the python standard library which does this for me.

Comment: What do you think `*` and `**` are? What are you talking about?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about here. Are you looking for a way to intercept calls using `*` and `**` argument expansion? If so there is none, because that has nothing to do with the object being called.

Comment: If you are looking for the *operators* for multiplication and exponentiation, then there are special methods for that, but you need to be a lot clearer as to what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you were right with your first guess, they probably don't have a firm grasp of argument expansion.

Comment: After your update: the `*` and `**` syntax results in different bytecode being produced by the compiler. There is no way to reproduce that with a 'magic function', no. I'd find using a different method to reproduce the same results *less readable* anyway, as you'd confuse experienced programmers.

Comment: I guess you're looking for [`apply`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply), but Python docs explicitly say splats are the preferred way.

Comment: This might be helpful: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526300/does-argument-unpacking-use-iteration-or-item-getting >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## YES, THERE IS AN EQUIVALENT

Technically, you can use the builtin [`apply()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#non-essential-built-in-functions) function. According to the python docs:

> The use of apply() is equivalent to function(*args, **keywords).

so you can do `apply(function, args, keywords=None)`. (`keywords` is optional.)

## BUT DON'T USE IT

On top of being non-idiomatic and confusing to more experienced programmers, this function [has been deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#non-essential-built-in-functions) **and should not be used in new code:**

> Deprecated since version 2.3: Use function(*args, **keywords) instead of apply(function, args, keywords)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a function that does the same thing as `*` or `**`. You'd have to modify `method` itself. The reason is that the `remove_magic` function could return a tuple/list at best, but you already have one:

```
a = (1,2,3)
method(remove_magic(a))
```

A pythonic alternative might be to unpack the tuple and to pass the arguments explicitly:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
x, y, z = a
method(x, y, z)
```

In Python 2.x, you can use `apply`, but I don't find it more legible. Its also not available in python 3.

```
apply(method, a)
```

The official reccomendation is to simply stick with

```
method(*a)
```